# Function of arc every few steps along cone

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, 3d

So I have no way how to properly explain this.
I have no idea how to solve this problem.

Given the following:

In a 3D world, we have a normalized vector $V(x_v, y_v, z_v)$, a starting point $S(x_s, y_s, z_s)$ and a radius r, as illustrated in the following image, and the vector $V$ is on the same plane as the entire orange circle with middle point $S$ and radius `r`, and given that the dotted line below is always parallel to the "floor", so the two points of our blue triangle on the orange circle have an equal `y` value.:

[image: Very good drawing]

Now given that the angle of alpha is 60 degrees, s.t. the blue triangle becomes an equilateral triangle with sides of length `r`.

What I want, is the following, and I honestly have no clue how:

[image]

Given `n` concentric arcs between the two lines of the blue triangle, equally spaced s.t. $r = n \cdot d$.

Can I somehow get the function of each of those arcs somehow?

I know this question was asked so incredibly vague that it might not even make sense, but I tried my hardest to explain this the best i could.

Comment: What do you mean the function of each arc?  If you just want the coordinates of the arc, it is a piece of a circle, so $y=r \sin \theta, x=r \cos \theta$ if you measure $\theta$ from the rightward horizontal $x$ axis. $\theta$ is restricted to the range $[\frac {\pi - \alpha}2,\frac {\pi + \alpha}2]$

Comment: Basically what I want to do with each arc, is to divide it into $m_n$ points, where point $m=0$ is the point on the arc that intersects with one of the blue lines, and point $m=m_n-1$ on the other side, then to call $f_n(m)$ to get the coordinates of point $m$ on arc $n$.

Answer (score 0):

The radius of each arc is $r_k=\frac kn r$ where $k$ ranges from $1$ to $n$.  The points can be calculated by  taking intervals of $\theta$ from $0$ to $\alpha$ as $x=r_k \cos (\frac {\pi-\alpha}2+\theta),y=r_k \sin (\frac {\pi-\alpha}2+\theta)$, the standard parameterization of a circle.

Added:  the vertex of your angle is assumed to be the origin of the coordinates.  For 3D you can restrict $\theta$ to $[0,\alpha /2]$, which will give you the point in the $xy$ plane with $x \ge 0$.  Now you can revolve it around the $y$ axis.  The $y$ values are all the same.  Given the $x$ we calculated for a given $\theta$ the point is $(x',y,z)$ with $x'=x \cos \phi, z=x \sin \phi$ as $\phi$ ranges from $0$ to $2\pi$  The shape is no longer an arc, which is what led me to the 2D solution.  It is now a spherical cap.

Comment: But this is in 3D space, thus theres also a z coordinate. Which is pointing out og the screen when looking at my illustrations. Also, i assume I add the x and y values from the starting point to this, but is the vector itself not used?